# Trouble with simple Hex to Int Calculation

Tags: binary, hex

The specifications for mp4 files outlines its contained matrix. For which, it describes:

The matrix provides a transformation matrix for the video: (u,v,w) are restricted here to (0,0,1) with types (uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t), with hex values : (0,0,0x40000000). u, v and w, are stored as 2.30 fixed-point values.

Putting all context aside, **can someone please explain to me how 0x40000000 is equal to 1 as a 2.30 fixed-point value in an unsigned Int(32) variable?**

I'm getting 2, not 1. FYI, I'm new to these things.

Comment: Can you show your process for getting 2?

Comment: Sure, I used a converter to convert 0x40000000 in to binary => 1000000000000000000000000000000. Left me with 10 to the left of the decimal, which I calculated as 2

Comment: Did you check how long that value was?

Comment: Yup, sorry posted before I finished writing, just edited it

Comment: I don’t think your edit answers that :P

Comment: :O, so the converter obviously didn't know that it was 32bit, so it left out the 0's to the left? Is that what happened?

Comment: 0x40000000=01.0000...0000. In 2.30 fixed point (signed), it is equal to 1.0

Comment: Thank @Ry, got the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
0x40000000 = 0b01000000000000000000000000000000
         2 ----^^
       .30 ------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The first two bits are `01`, representing 1. The last thirty bits are `00…0`, representing 0/2<sup>30</sup>. Add them together to get 1.

Alternatively, 0x40000000/2<sup>30</sup> is also 1.